# Is there a way to check if a string contains at least one capital letter recursively with java?

Tags: java, string, recursion, boolean

I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exceptions probably because of the `charAt` method but I'm stuck.
I know I have to use `isUpperCase` but I'm not sure exactly where.

```
public static boolean hasCapitals(String s) {
    if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return hasCapitals(s.substring(1));
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args ){
    System.out.println( hasCapitals( "New Hampshire" ) ); // returns true
    System.out.println( hasCapitals( "word" ) ); // returns false
    System.out.println( hasCapitals( "I" ) ); // returns true
    System.out.println( hasCapitals( "" ) ); // returns false
}
```

Comment: You should add a check like if `s.isEmpty()`, return `false` .

Comment: What happens when you reach the end of the string before any uppercase letter is found? You need to handle that case

Comment: if `s` is empty, what is the value of `s.charAt(0)`?

Comment: you need to iterate over the string. first convert the string to char array(char[]) and iterate over it and check in the loop. when you have the loop iteration, you can refactor it to be recurse

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to do it recursively? If not, there is a very simple solution. If `string.equals(string.toLowerCase()) = true`, then the string does not contain an uppercase letter.

Comment: I'm dumb and forgot the base case to return false. However, I still am having problems with the out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: This is just a practice problem for me and I have to find a way to complete it recursively without any loops.

Comment: Just `return !s.isEmpty() && (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) || hasCapitals(s.substring(1)));` No need for an `if` statement here.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a breaking condition in recursion to finally come out. That condition is missing in your code and you are getting the exception when length of your string is 1.

Try checking String's length before calling isUpperCase.

```
public static boolean hasCapitals(String s) {
    if(s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))) {
        return true;
    } else if(s.length() > 1){
        return hasCapitals(s.substring(1));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `null` check was not demanded. On the other hand, this code will still fail with an exception when an empty string is passed to it.

Comment: Changed null to an empty string and it worked! Thank you so much

Comment: Yes you are right. Added the additional check for empty string.

Comment: You can use `s.isEmpty()` instead of `s.length() == 0`…

Answer (score 0):

try like this, does exactly what you need

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( hasCapitals( "New Hampshire", 0 ) );
    System.out.println( hasCapitals( "word", 0 ) );
    System.out.println( hasCapitals( "I", 0 ) );
    System.out.println( hasCapitals( "", 0 ) );
    System.out.println( hasCapitals( "hamPshire", 0 ) );
}

private static boolean hasCapitals(String value, int index) {
    if(value.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    if(Character.isUpperCase(value.charAt(index))) {
        return true;
    } else if(value.length() > (index + 1)) {
        return hasCapitals(value, index + 1);
    } 

    return false;

}
```